# React-Bootstrap Form.Check weird behaviour on first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to do filtering on a list of objects, and have made a useState object which will hold the state of all filters, which looks like this:

```
const [filterState, setFilterState] = useState({
    "sell": false,
    "buy": false,
    "startDate": "",
    "endDate": "",
    "location": "",
    "music": false,
    "theatre": false,
    "movie": false,
});
```

I'm using two Form.Check from "react-bootstrap" to change the "sell" and "buy" fields, but they are giving me some issues, the filterState object doesn't change until I have clicked the Form.Check objects twice, only the UI updates correctly, which is weird when the filterState object decides the checked state. So what is shown is the opposite of what the filterState object's state is.

Code for the Form.Check fields:

```
<Form.Check checked={filterState.buy} onChange={onBuyChange} id="buy" type="checkbox" label={`Ønskes kjøpt`}/>
<Form.Check checked={filterState.sell} onChange={onSellChange} id="sell" type="checkbox" label={`Til salgs`}/>
```

The onChange functions:

```
const onSellChange = () => {
    setFilterState({
            ...filterState,
            "sell": !filterState.sell
        }
    );
    console.log(filterState);
}

const onBuyChange = () => {
    setFilterState({
            ...filterState,
            "buy": !filterState.buy
        }
    );
    console.log(filterState);
}
```

#### Examples

Initial state:
[image]

Clicking once doesn't change the state:
[image]

Clicking again updates the state, but it's now it's of sync:
[image]

---

##### Printing before and after setFilterState

Another weird behavior I get is that printing the filterState before and after setFilterState gives the same output. Should filterState be changed before it goes to the next line? Is setFilterState working asynchronously somehow, which can make Form.Check read from it before  the value has changed?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

useState's set function runs asynchronously, so I needed useEffect.
Using useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    filterEvents();
}, [filterState]);
```

With the same code as above, this filters the events displayed whenever the filterState changes, which is what I needed. Thanks to Juho Vepsäläinen for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```js
const onSellChange = () => {
    setFilterState(filterState => ({
            ...filterState,
            "sell": !filterState.sell
        })
    );
}

const onBuyChange = () => {
    setFilterState(filterState => ({
            ...filterState,
            "buy": !filterState.buy
        })
    );
}
```

I cannot guarantee it will work but it feels like the problem has to do with the way state is derived so I made your setters pick up the previous one called async. That way React should be able to resolve it correctly.

Comment: It gives the exact same behavior unfortunately.

Comment: Can you set up as tiny example as possible on something like https://codesandbox.io/ ? It's enough if it has only the component and a bit of state in it.

Comment: I added print before and after the setFilterState, and the state doesn't seem to change directly after, so it looks like an async issue, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-nightingale-x9h448?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Note that for the print to make sense, you should print inside the callback that sets the state (i.e. inside `setFilterState`). The state seems to work exactly as I would expect at https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sanne-tmvuv3?file=/src/App.js .

Comment: I see. I just now am learning about the useState callback parameter. I expect it to call the function I pass into it, only after the filterState is ready to be read after a setFilterState (which is exactly what I need), but when I try to use it on console.log in my sandbox example, the value before and after is still the same. Sandbox with extended prints to showcase: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-wood-of1u5d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I set up an example that's using effect for tracking and the output looks exactly what I would expect: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-black-1vsivs?file=/src/App.js .

Comment: Thank you, this helped me make it work!  Still not sure why the callback of useState didn't work as I expected, but useEffect did the trick, I'll post an answer.

Comment: The interesting point is that the callback of useState isn't documented officially. I imagine it's not triggering when we imagine it to trigger.